# .net core API cant connect PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core

I want to create a very simple API using .netCore and PostgreSQL database, here is my app setting

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=192.xxx.xx.xx;Port=5433;Database=ltw_central_db;User Id=UserNAme;Password = myPass; Timeout = 15;"
}
```

but I get an error which says Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0
I googled the error and i learned this error indicates something is wrong with my connection string but seems my connection string is fine, any idea?

here is the controller I want tp query and i get error:

```
   private readonly TenMinutesContext _context;
    public ValuesController(TenMinutesContext context)
    {

        _context = context;
    }
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var s = _context.stat10mins.Take(5).ToList();

        return null;
    }
```

My DbContext:

```
 public TenMinutesContext(DbContextOptions<TenMinutesContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<TenMinutes> stat10mins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //  modelBuilder.("wpv");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TenMinutes>().ToTable("v_statistics_10_m", "wpv");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

In Appsetting

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<TenMinutesContext>(opt =>
            opt.UseNpgsql("TenMinutes"));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        var connection = @"Server=192.xxx.xx.xx;Port=5433;Database=ltw_central_db;User Id=UserNAme;Password = myPass; Timeout = 15;";
        services.AddDbContext<TenMinutesContext>
            (options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));

    }
```

Comment: What is the code using this connection string?

Comment: Do you somewhere define that it should use PostgreSQL so it’s not trying to use some other provider?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i updated my question by adding appsetting,there im using Npgsql which is the provider,and i also installed npgsql for .net core from nuget

Comment: `services.AddDbContext<TenMinutesContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql("TenMinutes"));` "TenMinutes" is indeed an invalid connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services.AddDbContext<TenMinutesContext>(opt =>
        opt.UseNpgsql("TenMinutes"));

    var connection = @"Server=192.xxx.xx.xx;Port=5433;Database=ltw_central_db;User Id=UserNAme;Password = myPass; Timeout = 15;";
    services.AddDbContext<TenMinutesContext>
        (options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));
```

You have used two `AddDbContext` and the first one is incorrect.

I have tried your code using localhost server (`Server=localhost`) and it will have the same error like what you have gotten.

It works well when I remove below code.

```
services.AddDbContext<TenMinutesContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql("TenMinutes"));
```

For EF core in Postgresql, refer to:

http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

Comment: can you show me where i have used two db context?and by removing that my code never reaches controller

Comment: @mortezasol see the first line of my answer which copied from your posted code...